# White light isn't white

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

When I open a new blender file, my lamp emission color is a greyish pink, even with the RGB-values all set to 1/1/1.
Setting everything back to factory defaults gives me a white "backlight", but still - opening a new file gives me this pinkish greyish standard sun. 
No, it's not the monitor - I have perfect white in other applications (like the browser right now...)
Any idea why?

Comment: Check `Color Management`, default mode should be RGB

Comment: What the..! That's the culprit, was switched to DCI-P3! Do they sometimes change all by themselves? Because I know for sure sRGB is the correct value...

Comment: That sometime happens, when I create additional Scenes. Also don't know why